# GLSL Line Pattern — Changing Colors

Tags: glsl, shader

I am trying to change the colours at the pen below to black and white. I am having trouble finding the right values. Can someone help me in finding the solution?

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/pkid/pen/WNbJNBw)

Here is the part of the html that I believe should be changed (I might be wrong though):

```c
float noiseHue = noise(vec3(randIndexHue, randIndexHue, time));
float hue = mix(0.111, 0.138, randIndexHue + (noiseHue * 0.5));
vec4 grain = addGrain(ouv, time, 0.15);
vec3 color = HSLToRGB(vec3(hue, 1.0, 0.5));
vec3 bgColor = HSLToRGB(vec3(0.772, mix(0.75, 1.0, mouseDistance), mix(0.1, 0.25, mouseDistance)));
float val = dline * (mouseDistance * 0.5 + 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Black is RGB(0, 0, 0) and white is RGB(1, 1, 1). All you have to do is to set `color = vec3(1.0)` and `bgColor = vec3(0.0)` (instead of `HSLToRGB`):

```c
vec3 color = vec3(1.0);
vec3 bgColor = vec3(0.0);

float val = dline * (mouseDistance * 0.5 + 0.5);
vec3 albedo = mix(bgColor, color, val);
gl_FragColor = vec4(albedo, 1.0) + grain;
```

See the example:

```js
//Create var for the contenair, the webGL 3D scene, uniforms to bind into shader and timer

var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var uniforms;
var startTime;


var cols = 50.;
var rows  = 50.0;

init(); //init scene
animate(); //updateScene

function init() {
 //get contenaire
 container = document.getElementById('container');
 
 //Create THREE.JS scene and timer
 startTime = Date.now();
 camera = new THREE.Camera();
 camera.position.z = 1;
 scene = new THREE.Scene();
 
 //create a simple plance
 var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(16, 9);
 
 //create uniform table which provide all our GLSL binding
 uniforms = {
  time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
  resolution: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2() },
  colsrows: {type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2()},
  mouse: {type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2()}
 };
 
 //create THREE.JS material
 var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
 //set shaders and uniforms into material
  uniforms: uniforms,
  vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent
 } );

 //create mesh, add it to the scene
 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
 scene.add(mesh);
 
 //create renderer and add it to the DOM
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 
 //check window for resize This will give us the proper resolution values to bind
 onWindowResize();
 window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
 
}

function onWindowResize(event) {
 container.style.height = window.innerHeight+"px";
 container.style.width = window.innerWidth+"px";
 
 canvasWidth = container.offsetWidth;
 canvasHeight = container.offsetHeight;
 //send new size value to the shader and resize the window
 uniforms.resolution.value.x = canvasWidth;
 uniforms.resolution.value.y = canvasHeight;
 
 //var res = canvasWidth / cols;
 //rows = canvasHeight / res;
 uniforms.colsrows.value.x = cols;
 uniforms.colsrows.value.y = rows;//rows;
 
 renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
}

function animate() {
 render();
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function render() {
 var currentTime = Date.now();
 var elaspedSeconds =  (currentTime - startTime) / 1000.0;
 var maxTime = 4.0;
 var normTime = (elaspedSeconds % maxTime) / maxTime;
 uniforms.time.value = elaspedSeconds * 1.0;

 renderer.render(scene, camera);
}


function move(ev){
  mx = ev.clientX
   my = ev.clientY;
 // console.log(mx+" , "+my);
 
 uniforms.mouse.value.x = mx;
 uniforms.mouse.value.y = my;
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', move)
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background : #1a1a1a;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  cursor: none;
}

#container{
 background : black;
 color : white;
   margin: auto;
 width : 500px;
 height : 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<!--script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script-->

<div id="container"></div> 

<!-- GLSL SCRIPT -->
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
 void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
 }
</script>

<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  #define TWO_PI 6.28318530718
  #define EPSILON 0.000011
  uniform vec2 resolution;
  uniform float time;
  uniform vec2 colsrows;
  uniform vec2 mouse;
 
  float HueToRGB(float f1, float f2, float hue)
  {
   if (hue < 0.0)
    hue += 1.0;
   else if (hue > 1.0)
    hue -= 1.0;
   float res;
   if ((6.0 * hue) < 1.0)
    res = f1 + (f2 - f1) * 6.0 * hue;
   else if ((2.0 * hue) < 1.0)
    res = f2;
   else if ((3.0 * hue) < 2.0)
    res = f1 + (f2 - f1) * ((2.0 / 3.0) - hue) * 6.0;
   else
    res = f1;
   return res;
  }


  vec3 HSLToRGB(vec3 hsl)
  {
   vec3 rgb;

   if (hsl.y == 0.0)
    rgb = vec3(hsl.z); // Luminance
   else
   {
    float f2;

    if (hsl.z < 0.5)
     f2 = hsl.z * (1.0 + hsl.y);
    else
     f2 = (hsl.z + hsl.y) - (hsl.y * hsl.z);

    float f1 = 2.0 * hsl.z - f2;

    rgb.r = HueToRGB(f1, f2, hsl.x + (1.0/3.0));
    rgb.g = HueToRGB(f1, f2, hsl.x);
    rgb.b= HueToRGB(f1, f2, hsl.x - (1.0/3.0));
   }

   return rgb;
  }
 
  mat2 rotate2d(float _angle){
   return mat2(cos(_angle),-sin(_angle),
      sin(_angle),cos(_angle));
  }
  
  vec2 rotateFrom(vec2 uv, vec2 center, float angle){
   vec2 uv_ = uv - center;
   uv_ =  rotate2d(angle) * uv_;
   uv_ = uv_ + center;

   return uv_;
  }
  
  float random(float value){
   return fract(sin(value) * 43758.5453123);
  }
  
  float random(vec2 tex){
   return fract(sin(dot(tex.xy, vec2(12.9898, 78.233))) * 43758.5453123);
  }
  
  vec2 random2D(vec2 uv){
   uv = vec2(dot(uv, vec2(127.1, 311.7)), dot(uv, vec2(269.5, 183.3)));
   //return -1.0 + 2.0 * fract(sin(uv) * 43758.5453123);
   return fract(sin(uv) * 43758.5453123); //return without offset on x, y
  }

  vec3 random3D(vec3 uv){
   uv = vec3(dot(uv, vec3(127.1, 311.7, 120.9898)), dot(uv, vec3(269.5, 183.3, 150.457)), dot(uv, vec3(380.5, 182.3, 170.457)));
   return -1.0 + 2.0 * fract(sin(uv) * 43758.5453123);
  }
 
  float cubicCurve(float value){
   return value * value * (3.0 - 2.0 * value); // custom cubic curve
  }

  vec2 cubicCurve(vec2 value){
   return value * value * (3.0 - 2.0 * value); // custom cubic curve
  }

  vec3 cubicCurve(vec3 value){
   return value * value * (3.0 - 2.0 * value); // custom cubic curve
  }

  float noise(vec2 uv){
   vec2 iuv = floor(uv);
   vec2 fuv = fract(uv);
   vec2 suv = cubicCurve(fuv);

   float dotAA_ = dot(random2D(iuv + vec2(0.0)), fuv - vec2(0.0));
   float dotBB_ = dot(random2D(iuv + vec2(1.0, 0.0)), fuv - vec2(1.0, 0.0));
   float dotCC_ = dot(random2D(iuv + vec2(0.0, 1.0)), fuv - vec2(0.0, 1.0));
   float dotDD_ = dot(random2D(iuv + vec2(1.0, 1.0)), fuv - vec2(1.0, 1.0));

   return mix(
    mix(dotAA_, dotBB_, suv.x),
    mix(dotCC_, dotDD_, suv.x),
    suv.y);
  }

  float noise(vec3 uv){
   vec3 iuv = floor(uv);
   vec3 fuv = fract(uv);
   vec3 suv = cubicCurve(fuv);

   float dotAA_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(0.0)), fuv - vec3(0.0));
   float dotBB_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)), fuv - vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
   float dotCC_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)), fuv - vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
   float dotDD_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)), fuv - vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0));

   float dotEE_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)), fuv - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
   float dotFF_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)), fuv - vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0));
   float dotGG_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(0.0, 1.0, 1.0)), fuv - vec3(0.0, 1.0, 1.0));
   float dotHH_ = dot(random3D(iuv + vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)), fuv - vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));

   float passH0 = mix(
    mix(dotAA_, dotBB_, suv.x),
    mix(dotCC_, dotDD_, suv.x),
    suv.y);

   float passH1 = mix(
    mix(dotEE_, dotFF_, suv.x),
    mix(dotGG_, dotHH_, suv.x),
    suv.y);

   return mix(passH0, passH1, suv.z);
  }
 
  float drawLine(vec2 uv, vec2 p1, vec2 p2, float r)
  {
   //from https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MtlSDr
   vec2 l = p2 - p1;
   float L = length(l);
   float L2 = L*L;

   float d1 = length(uv - p1);
   float d2 = length(uv - p2);
   float d  = min(d1, d2);
   float ds = dot(uv - p1, l);
   if (ds >= 0.0 && ds <= L2)
   {
    vec2 n = vec2(-l.y, l.x) / L;
    d = min(d, abs(dot(uv - p1, n)));
   }

   return 1.0 - smoothstep(0.0, 0.01, d - r);
  }
 
  vec2 fishey(vec2 uv, vec2 center, float ratio, float dist){
     vec2 puv = uv + vec2(1.0);
    //center coords
     vec2 m = vec2(center.x, center.y/ratio) + vec2(1.0);
     //vector from center to current fragment
     vec2 d = puv - m;
     // distance of pixel from center
     float r = sqrt(dot(d, d)); 
     //amount of effect
     float power = ( TWO_PI / (2.0 * sqrt(dot(m, m)))) * mix(0.1, 0.4, pow(dist, 0.75));
     //radius of 1:1 effect
     float bind;
     if (power > 0.0) bind = sqrt(dot(m, m));//stick to corners
     //else {if (ratio < 1.0) bind = m.x; else bind = m.y;}//stick to borders

     //Weird formulas
     vec2 nuv;
     if (power > 0.0)//fisheye
    nuv = m + normalize(d) * tan(r * power) * bind / tan( bind * power);
     else if (power < 0.0)//antifisheye
      nuv = m + normalize(d) * atan(r * -power * 10.0) * bind / atan(-power * bind * 10.0);
     else 
    nuv = puv;//no effect for power = 1.0

   return nuv - vec2(1.0);
  }
 
  vec4 addGrain(vec2 uv, float time, float grainIntensity){
      float grain = random(fract(uv * time)) * grainIntensity;
      return vec4(vec3(grain), 1.0);
  }
  
  void main(){
   vec2 ouv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
   vec2 uv = ouv;
   
   float ratio = resolution.x / resolution.y;
   vec2 nmouse = vec2(mouse.x, mouse.y) / resolution.xy;
   nmouse.y = 1.0 - nmouse.y;
   float maxDist = 0.35;
   float blurEdge = maxDist * 0.5;
   float blurEdge2 = maxDist * 1.0;
   vec2 mouseToUV = (uv - nmouse) / vec2(1.0, ratio);
   float mouseDistance = 1.0 - smoothstep(maxDist - blurEdge, maxDist, length(mouseToUV));
   float mouseDistance2 = 1.0 - smoothstep(maxDist - blurEdge2, maxDist, length(mouseToUV));
   
   
   uv = fishey(uv, nmouse, ratio,  mouseDistance2);
   uv = rotateFrom(uv, vec2(0.5), time * 0.1);
   //animate y
   //wave
   uv.y /= ratio;
   vec2 basedUV = uv + vec2(1.0);
   float complexityX = 10.0;
   float complexityY = 10.0;
   float maxAmp = mix(0.05, 0.75, mouseDistance);
   float amp = 0.01 * mouseDistance + noise(vec3(basedUV.x * complexityX, basedUV.y * complexityY, time * 0.1)) * maxAmp;
   float theta = time + mouseDistance + basedUV.y * (TWO_PI);
   uv.x = fract(uv.x + sin(theta) * amp);
   //divide into cols rows
   vec2 nuv = uv * colsrows;
   vec2 fuv = fract(nuv);
   vec2 iuv = floor(nuv);
   
   float minSpeed = 1.0;
   float maxSpeed = 5.0;
   float speed = minSpeed + random(floor(uv.x * colsrows.x)) * (maxSpeed - minSpeed);
   fuv.y = fract(fuv.y + time * speed);
   
   //draw dash line
   float minWeight = 0.005 + random(vec2(iuv.x, 0.0)) * 0.05;
   float strokeWeight = mix(minWeight, minWeight * 5.0, mouseDistance);
   float dlineWidth = mix(1.0, 0.25 - strokeWeight, mouseDistance);//0.5 - strokeWeight;
   float dline = drawLine(fuv, vec2(0.5, 0.5 - dlineWidth * 0.5), vec2(0.5, 0.5 + dlineWidth * 0.5), strokeWeight);
   
   float randIndexHue = random(vec2(iuv.x + floor(time), 0.0));
   float noiseHue = noise(vec3(randIndexHue, randIndexHue, time));
   float hue = mix(0.111, 0.138, randIndexHue + (noiseHue * 0.5));
   vec4 grain = addGrain(ouv, time, 0.15);
   //vec3 color = HSLToRGB(vec3(hue, 1.0, 0.5));
   //vec3 bgColor = HSLToRGB(vec3(0.772, mix(0.75, 1.0, mouseDistance), mix(0.1, 0.25, mouseDistance)));
      vec3 color = vec3(1.0);
   vec3 bgColor = vec3(0.0);
   float val = dline * (mouseDistance * 0.5 + 0.5);
   
   vec3 albedo = mix(bgColor, color, val);
   
   gl_FragColor = vec4(albedo, 1.0) + grain;
  }
</script>
```